# How to save my Crepe Myrtle bonzai from expected death during next winter?

Tags: bonsai

I had the hardest time making a seedling `Crepe Myrtles` this spring. One died because I touched it like a noob then it bended an died -_-. The other one had not enough sun so it dried out and died, another one died because I tried inside and I think it was too cold...

Then I finally manage to save one from death by putting it outside under the morning sun and inside a small greenhouse to keep humidity. It had now like 4 pair of leaves and it's still pretty small. I don't know what to do with it during winter since I don't have a lot of sun in my apartment and it's pretty cold (20-21 Celsius)

I live in **Quebec City**, Canada where winter are long and very cold. So, I don't think I could let it outside, but at the same time, I can't really bring it inside since it won't be in a dormant state...

Would it be safe if I buy an hydroponic lamp with a timer during winter? I read that it's not an Indoor Plant... Do you have any other suggestion ?

[image: bonsai]
[image: bonsai]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is definitely a solution here.  You have to bring your bonsai inside for winter unless you have a heated, very consistently heated greenhouse.  The way to do this is to HARDEN your plant (backwards I guess) to get used to the less humid, less light, drafty home environment.  Bring your plant inside for half an hour everyday for 3 or 4 days, increase the amount of time to and hour, then 2 hours then 4 hours. Give it a place of its own with lots of light but not direct light.  Definitely near a window.  If you see any stress in your bonsai cut the time inside by half.  Bonsai needs to be watered every day (discuss this with a Bonsai master depends on the size of your plant and its pot) and I found tap water to be a death wish.  Get distilled or bottled water.  Or use a friend's well water.  No saucer beneath, easy easy on fertilizer during the winter months.  Then in spring, harden your bonsai the other direction.  A great spot is a covered porch. The daylight will be short, the reduction in fertilizer will put your tree in a semi dormancy as if it were in a Japanese winter.  Put it in a sunny, cool room, like a guest room. No pruning, no cold or warm drafts.

If I were you I'd get advice from Bonsai masters!  Bonsai is the ultimate training tool for gardeners!

Comment: Even if the winter is like 8 month here? Will it last that long? I read on the notice that his winter are suppose to last 3 months... That's cute but here in Montréal, Canada, 3 months is the summer haha

Comment: That plant will go into a semi dormancy just because of the light dark cycles.  You can acclimate this bonsai to the home environment and in the spring begin to harden off your bonsai back into the out of doors.  BABY this plant.  Everything is slow, methodical and take no chances.  I would find a cooler room, lots of light or a heated greenhouse and make that your bonsai's home.  I know your climate.  My indoor plants go outside under a porch roof for as long as safe then come back inside...for winter.  They are able to make lots of food for themselves to last the winter.

Comment: I'm a little lost here,you said " I would find a cooler room, lots of light or a heated greenhouse"?  But I though during dormancy, it didn't need any light...

Comment: http://www.majordifferences.com/2013/12/difference-between-light-and-dark.html#.V7YrQ_krKM8...check this article.  Light is important as well as dark...dormancy is a bit different on a different scale.  If the leaves completely fall off then no light is necessary.  Plants in pots, allowed to be outside, their roots are vulnerable to the cold.  The most vulnerable part of a plant are the roots.  Thus the babying.  Your plant is not normal.  Dormancy might happen but because you are controlling the environment it just might stay in a semi dormancy and needs a bit of light.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. I might have few other question lol... I made the stupid mistake of planting the seed in a small bonzai pot...I realized later that you start training your bonzai after 2-3 years ... Should I transplant it in a bigger pot before summer end? Also, when should I start bringing it inside to prepare it for winter? I want it to be as strong as he could get before winter

Comment: Starts don't do well in Bonsai pots...I'd just take your seedling and put it in a very small pot with potting soil to get it started before the process of bonsai.  I've had the prettiest crepe myrtle babies but they were happy in 3 or 4" pots, great drainage, little or no fertilizer until large enough for a 6" pot. Then, I THINK would be a good time to train into a bonsai.  You gotta find a bonsai master!  What fun...please send pictures!  We can help get you a healthy plant but farther takes a master of bonsai.  Send pictures!!  Find a 'master'...!

Comment: I repotted it today, It still look pretty fragile. I added pictures and I seeking a bonsai master :)

Comment: Sure it is fragile but I am seeing a very healthy seeding.  The pot is a bit big so please do not over water.  Water only enough to keep moisture around the roots. Do NOT soak all of that soil.  That little guy doesn't have the root structure with which to suck up the water so any water where the roots are not will become root rot facilities.  Do not transplant again.  When you put it in this pot how did the roots look?  Were they a mass conforming to the original pot?  This must be a 4" pot looks like and that is just fine.  Keep it moist NEVER WET. Forget the fertilizers!  Give it some time!

Comment: I used to put fertilizer every week... I'll stop right now then... I didn't see the root much as I was scared to hurt them. It wasn't filling the old pot that's for sure. I'd say it was a little smaller than what goes out of the soil. And the soil doesnt seems to dry out... It's always wet, so maybe I shout put it in the glass house to avoid rain. Thanks a lot for your advice, i'm a little more confident :)

Comment: No problem...did you add fertilizer to this new soil?  Did it come with fertilizer...the potting soil (you DID use potting soil,yes?).  Fertilizer can kill easier than overwatering.  Even using very diluted fertilizer.  Young plants should not be fertilized unless you know what you are doing and what your plant needs.  This little tree does not need fertilizer for a while.  YES!!  You are in control of the environment of this cutie!  Out of the rain, any possible cutworm on the prowl, a hungry rat!!  Stay in touch, let's make this guy thrive, OK?  Grins!

Comment: I used potting soil and I added very diluted bonsai fertilizer, but i'll stop that one for a while... Gladly it didn't seems to affect it yet.

Comment: It isn't a bonsai yet!  You need a healthy plant and I believe that is showing bark before training into a bonsai.  I am excited you are looking for a bonsai master/class!!  No more fertilizer for awhile.  Bonsai fertilizer is already weak!  Don't want too much vigorous growth if one is a Bonsai!!  You are doing well!  If the leaves start curling under and the green becomes a darker green take a picture and contact us!  That is a good sign of too much fertilizer.  Then we'll have you dump the soil and repot, possibly rinsing the soil with too much fertilizer off.  But I think your plant is OK!

Comment: Cute little greenhouse, in full sun however could easily fry little baby plants.  This winter that little guy would do well in there keeping it out of direct sun and adding ventilation (opening the roof and using one of those teensy tiny fans!  Put plant and pot right inside (you should not have to up pot until next year) get the pot bottom lifted up so there is air beneath pot and surface for drainage. Do not water until dryish!  During the winter you do not want to fertilize unless your plant is showing signs of deficiencies.  Spring time that bonsai fertilizer would be fine.  Send info...

Comment: That plant and pot should go into the house in that little 'terrarium' green house...do not leave outside.  Especially not crepe myrtle!  Sorry should have edited first.

Comment: I don't think you'll need to repot that guy until mid spring next year.  Seriously.  Be careful not to overwater!  I'd even take your plant out during the day and bring it into your home at night.  When it starts getting colder leave it inside longer until it is completely used to the dryer less light environment of your home.  In that little greenhouse it will be easy to control the humidity.

Comment: You would start right now bringing it inside? Or wait a little bit since I just reppoted it? It's still 28 degres here in Canada, but in few weeks it will go under 20°...

Comment: Also, it might be more dry inside, but it wont go under 18-20° inside during the winter... Shouldn't it supposed to be less than 10° to be in dormancy?

Comment: I dont really have a place which goes in between 0-10° AND have sunlight... :/

Comment: Starting and training a little baby tree one does not have to get it into dormancy!  It will be in a semi dormancy where it won't lose its leaves, keeping it on the cooler side, no fertilizer, water sparingly and giving it some light is perfect.  Your bonsai teacher should be able to explain how little trees are different than big established trees.  Keep it in the little green house with the roof open.  Leave a platter of pebbles and water on one side the plant on the other.  Close it up at night open during the day.  Get a tiny fan for air movement!!  Improves growth.

Comment: Hey there, Winter is almost here, i tried to slowly enter my bonsai inside for it to accutumate but now that its always inside, the lower leaf are slowly starting to die... I updated my question, what do you think?